# What is the orbital motion where both foci are located at one point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

What is the orbital motion where both foci are located at one point? I know that an ellipse orbit is motion with two distinct foci.

Comment: Sounds like a circle answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

This image of conic sections will solve your question.

[image: conic section]